# how to add values from array to Bootstrap combobox with search

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, combobox

I am using the bootstrap combobox with search which is working fine when populated with static options as follows:

```
<form role="form">
   <div class="form-group">
      <label>Select options</label>
      <select class="combobox input-large form-control" style="display: none;">
             <option value="" selected="selected">Type Planet name...</option>
             <option value="0">Mercury</option>
             <option value="1">Earth</option>
             <option value="2">Venus</option>
             <option value="3">Mars</option>
             <option value="4">Jupiter</option>
       </select>
   </div>
</form>
```

I want to load the options dynamically from an array. i tried ng-options and ng-repeat but the values are not coming inside the combo box. I will prefer using javascript.

Tried option:

```
<select class="combobox input-large form-control" style="display: none;"
        ng-model="PlanetData.selectedPlanet">
        option value="" selected="selected">Type for Planet...</option>
        <option ng-repeat="planet in PlanetData.availablePlanets" value="    {{planet.id}}">{{planet.planetName}}</option>
```

THis creates the combobox with the text "Type for channel", but the planetdata does not appear in the the combobox options rather it appears below it. I want to know how to bind the two so that the data comes in the combobox.

Comment: Please show the angular `ng-options` and `ng-repeat` you tried and/or the JavaScript you tried to load the values. There is nothing here displaying what you attempted or what errors you encountered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when the `combobox` function is called the ng-repeat or the ngOptions didn't rendered the options yet.

One quick way to fix this is call the `$('.combobox').combobox()` inside a `$timeout` callback.

```
$scope.items = [{id: 1, text: 'text1'}, {id: 2, text: 'text2'}];

$timeout(() => 
    $('.combobox').combobox(), 0);
```

See the plunker with this example: https://plnkr.co/edit/j25lasvpHxmMNUjl7EjE?p=preview

I tested with ngRepeat and ngOptions.

Comment: @rafaelpadovezi Thanks for your reply. I understood the reason for the data not to be rendered when the combobox function is called. But, with timeout now the data itself is not coming, earlier it was coming below the combobox. Am I again missing something ?

Comment: Hello Saahil, the data is coming from an ajax request? If so, be sure to call the $timeout only after you get the response.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var planet = ['Mercury','Mercury1'];

$.each(planet, function(index, value){
  
$('.combobox').append('<option value="'+index+'">'+value+'</option>');
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form role="form">
   <div class="form-group">
      <label>Select options</label>
      <select class="combobox input-large form-control">
           
       </select>
   </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was because of the ng-options or ng-repeat not getting rendered when the combobox was appearing. Refer to the answer from Rafael, it has all the necessary details. I used the timeout as he suggested and it worked like a charm.

$timeout(() =>
    $('.combobox').combobox(), 100);